# Arabic issue in RML reports OpenERP V7 (Odoo)

Tags: arabic, right-to-left, openerp-7, rml

Im facing a problem with OpenERP V7 regarding the arabic support in the RML reports.

1. The latest OpenERP (Odoo) community version 7
2. Ubuntu 12.04.5

The Issue: in order to support RTL in RML and arabic characters, I've installed arabicfix addons created by MGK IT Consulting, it installed  successfully but when printing an PDF report the results are various, in some reports, like customer invoice, its not working for the partner name, in other report, General Ledger report its not working for the account name but working for the partner name on the same report, and so on.

Not working = the arabic text is shown correctly but LTR instead of RTL

Tried to compare the two reports with no luck in finding out what makes the same field printed correct on one report and wrongly on another.

**Update**: it seems that the problem is limited to `<font>` tag, whenever its used within the RML the arabic direction is wrong, as a workaround, i've changed the RML reports and removed `<font>` tags from the fields where i have arabic text, it works!

Comment: Check https://github.com/barsi/openerp-rtl.

Comment: I did try all what is mentioned there,,, the generated PDF includes correct arabic and not working arabic in the same report, which means that the arabic support in the PDF is working, but why in some cases (mentioned in my initial post) is doesn't work? @Rawly

Comment: Did you create a translation to `arabic` language and set lang in RML file `setLang(o.partner_id.lang)`?